Extending an XAdES-XL signature to XAdES-A
I want to extend a XAdES-XL signature to XAdES-A by adding an Archive Timestamp. I have followed every step in section 5.5.2.2 of ETSI EN 319 132-1 V1.2.1 (2022-02), but I still receive an error stating that the archive timestamp hash value is incorrect.
Here is the signature file link: XAdES-XL
using var finalOctetStream = new MemoryStream();

    // ETSI EN 319 132-1 V1.2.1 (2022-02)
    
    // 5.5.2.2 >> Article 3
    // Take all the ds:Reference elements in their order of appearance within ds:SignedInfo referencing whatever the signer wants to sign including the SignedProperties element.
    // Process each one as indicated below: 

    foreach (Reference reference in XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.SignedInfo.References)
    {
        var uri = reference.Uri;
        
        byte[] referenceData;
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            //Full document
            referenceData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
        }
        else
        {
            //Select Uri target element
            var referencedNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode($"//*[@Id='{uri.Substring(1)}']");
            referenceData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(referencedNode.OuterXml);
        }
        
        if (reference.TransformChain != null && reference.TransformChain.Count > 0)
        {
            // 5.5.2.2 >> Artcile 3-C
            // If the ds:Reference element contains the ds:Transforms element, then apply all the transforms indicated within the ds:Transform children elements. After that: 
            foreach (var transform in reference.TransformChain)
                referenceData = XMLUtil.ApplyTransform(referenceData, (System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform)transform);
        
            // c) if the output of the last transform is a XML node-set according to XMLDSIG [1], canonicalize it as specified in clause 4.5 of the present document; 
            if (IsXmlNodeSet(referenceData))
                referenceData = XMLUtil.ApplyTransform(referenceData, new XmlDsigC14NTransform()); 
        }
        else
        {
            //b) if the retrieved data object is an XML node-set, then canonicalize it as specified in clause 4.5 of the present document;
            if (IsXmlNodeSet(referenceData))
                referenceData = XMLUtil.ApplyTransform(referenceData, new XmlDsigC14NTransform()); 
        }

        //d) Concatenate the resulting octets to the final octet stream. 
        finalOctetStream.Write(referenceData, 0, referenceData.Length);
    }

    // 5.5.2.2 >>> Article 4 
    // Take the following XMLDSIG elements in the order they are listed below, canonicalize each one as specified in clause 4.5, and concatenate each resulting octet stream to the final octet stream:
    // The ds:SignedInfo element.
    // The ds:SignatureValue element.
    // The ds:KeyInfo element, if present. 
    
    var signatureValueElementXpaths = new ArrayList() { "ds:SignedInfo", "ds:SignatureValue", "ds:KeyInfo" };
    
    // 5.5.2.2 >>> Article 5 and 6
    // Take the unsigned signature qualifying properties that appear before the current ArchiveTimeStamp in the order they appear within the UnsignedSignatureProperties,
    // canonicalize each one as specified in clause 4.5, and concatenate each resulting octet stream to the final octet stream. While concatenating, the following rules apply:

    signatureValueElementXpaths.Add("ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties/xades:SignatureTimeStamp");
    signatureValueElementXpaths.Add("ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties/xades:CompleteCertificateRefs");
    signatureValueElementXpaths.Add("ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties/xades:CompleteRevocationRefs");
    signatureValueElementXpaths.Add("ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties/xades:CertificateValues");
    signatureValueElementXpaths.Add("ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties/xades:RevocationValues");
    var canonizeData = XMLUtil.ComputeCanonicalizedValueOfElementList1(XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature, signatureValueElementXpaths, new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

    finalOctetStream.Write(canonizeData, 0, canonizeData.Length);

    
    // And send to timestamp server 
    var tstoken = GetTimeStampToken(SignatureTsa, finalOctetStream.ToArray(), SignatureType != SignatureType.XAdES_A);

    var archiveTimeStamp = new TimeStamp("ArchiveTimeStamp") {
        
        Id = "ArchiveTimeStamp-" + XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.Signature.Id,
        CanonicalizationMethod = new CanonicalizationMethod()
        {
            Algorithm = new XmlDsigC14NTransform().Algorithm
        }
    };

    archiveTimeStamp.EncapsulatedTimeStamp.PkiData = tstoken;

    archiveTimeStamp.EncapsulatedTimeStamp.Id = "ArchiveTimeStamp-" + Guid.NewGuid();

    unsignedProperties = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties;

    unsignedProperties.UnsignedSignatureProperties.ArchiveTimeStampCollection.Add(archiveTimeStamp);

    XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties = unsignedProperties;

    XL_signatureDocument.UpdateDocument();

I am trying to perform the validation using the XAdES Conformance Checker  and DSS 

I solved this problem. Here is my code that extends XAdES-XL signature to XAdES-A. Thanks to esig/dss
private static readonly byte[] xmlWithBomPreamble = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, (byte)'<' };
private static readonly byte[] xmlPreamble = new byte[] { (byte)'<' };
private static readonly HashSet<string> transformsWithNodeSetOutput = new HashSet<string>();
private static readonly string XP_WITH_ID_OPEN = "#xpointer(id(";


protected internal override XAdESSignedDocument ExtendXAdESSignature(XAdESSignedDocument xadesSignedDocument, UnsignedProperties unsignedProperties, SignatureParameters parameters,
    SignatureType currentSignatureType, IDocument originalData)
{
    if (SignatureType.XAdES_A >= currentSignatureType)
    {
        var XL_signatureDocument = base.ExtendXAdESSignature(xadesSignedDocument, unsignedProperties, parameters, currentSignatureType, originalData);

        var xadesSginature = new XAdESSignature(XL_signatureDocument, XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature);
        var messageInprint = xadesSginature.getArchiveTimestampData(0, originalData); 

        #region Arşiv Zaman Damgası Oluştur

        var tstoken = GetTimeStampToken(SignatureTsa, messageInprint, SignatureType != SignatureType.XAdES_A);

        var archiveTimeStamp = new TimeStamp("ArchiveTimeStamp", "xades141", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#")
        {
            Id = "ArchiveTimeStamp-" + XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.Signature.Id,
            CanonicalizationMethod = new CanonicalizationMethod()
            {
                Algorithm = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject.Algorithm
            }
        };

        archiveTimeStamp.EncapsulatedTimeStamp.PkiData = tstoken;

        archiveTimeStamp.EncapsulatedTimeStamp.Id = "ArchiveTimeStamp-" + Guid.NewGuid();

        #endregion

        #region İmzayı Güncelle

        unsignedProperties = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties;

        unsignedProperties.UnsignedSignatureProperties.ArchiveTimeStampCollection.Clear();

        XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties = unsignedProperties;

        //Eski arşiv zaman damgalarını kaldır. 
        XL_signatureDocument.UpdateDocument(true);

        unsignedProperties = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties;

        unsignedProperties.UnsignedSignatureProperties.ArchiveTimeStampCollection.Add(archiveTimeStamp);

        XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.UnsignedProperties = unsignedProperties;

        XL_signatureDocument.UpdateDocument();

        #endregion

        return XL_signatureDocument
    }

    return xadesSignedDocument
}

public virtual byte[] getArchiveTimestampData(int index, IDocument originalDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            var XL_signatureDocument = this.XAdEsSignedDocument;

            var xmlTransform = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject;

            using var finalOctetStream = new MemoryStream();

            #region Referansları Al

            foreach (Reference reference in XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.SignedInfo.References)
            {
                var referenceData = BuildRefernceUriData(reference, XL_signatureDocument, originalDocument);
                writeReferenceBytes(XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature, finalOctetStream, reference, referenceData, xmlTransform);
            }

            #endregion

            #region SignedIn fo, SignatureValue, KeyInfo Al

            var signatureValueElementXpaths = new ArrayList() { "ds:SignedInfo", "ds:SignatureValue", "ds:KeyInfo" };
            var canonizeData = XMLHelper.DoCanonicalizeElementList(XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature, signatureValueElementXpaths, xmlTransform);
            finalOctetStream.Write(canonizeData, 0, canonizeData.Length);

            #endregion

            #region Geçerli Arşiv Zaman Damgasından Önceki elemanları tek tek sırasıyla al

            var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(XL_signatureDocument.Document.NameTable);
            xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
            xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xades", XadesSignedXml.XadesNamespaceUri);

            var unsignedSignaturePropertiesNode = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.GetSignatureElement().SelectSingleNode("//xades:UnsignedProperties/xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties", xmlNamespaceManager);

            if (unsignedSignaturePropertiesNode != null)
            {
      
                // UnsignedSignatureProperties altındakileri döngüyle gez
                foreach (XmlNode node in unsignedSignaturePropertiesNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (node.LocalName == "ArchiveTimeStamp") 
                        break;

                    canonizeData = XMLHelper.ComputeCanonicalizedValueOfElement(XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature, node, xmlTransform);
                    finalOctetStream.Write(canonizeData, 0, canonizeData.Length);
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region Objects elementslerini al. QualifyingProperties hariç.

            var objList = XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature.Signature.ObjectList;

            foreach (DataObject crnObj in objList)
            {
                // DataObject'un birinci seviye alt elemanlarını al
                var dataObjectXml = crnObj.GetXml();
                var firstLevelChildNodes = dataObjectXml.ChildNodes;

                // İlk seviye çocuk elemanlar içinde "xades:QualifyingProperties" olup olmadığını kontrol et
                var containsQualifyingProperties = firstLevelChildNodes
                    .Cast<XmlNode>()
                    .Any(childNode => childNode.LocalName == "QualifyingProperties" && childNode.NamespaceURI == "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");


                if (containsQualifyingProperties)
                    continue;

                // Eğer "xades:QualifyingProperties" yoksa, canonicalization işlemini uygula
                canonizeData = XMLHelper.ComputeCanonicalizedValueOfElement(XL_signatureDocument.XadesSignature, dataObjectXml, xmlTransform);
                finalOctetStream.Write(canonizeData, 0, canonizeData.Length);
            }

            #endregion

            return finalOctetStream.ToArray();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.Message, new TamgaESException("XAdESSignature / getArchiveTimestampDataV2", e.Message, TamgaESErrorCodes.UYGULAMA_IC_HATA));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e.Message, new TamgaESException("XAdESSignature / getArchiveTimestampDataV2", e.Message, TamgaESErrorCodes.UYGULAMA_IC_HATA));
        }

        return null;
    }

private byte[] BuildRefernceUriData(Reference reference, XAdESSignedDocument signedDocument, IDocument originalDetachedData)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Refrans Digest Value : >> " + Convert.ToBase64String(reference.DigestValue));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference.Uri))
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedDocument.Document.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
        }
        else if (reference.Uri.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            ///İmzalanan Veri Belge İçinde bir referans

            var referencedNode = signedDocument.Document.SelectSingleNode($"//*[@Id='{reference.Uri.Substring(1)}' or @id='{reference.Uri.Substring(1)}']");

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(referencedNode.OuterXml);
        }
        else
        {
            return originalDetachedData.Content;
        }

        return null;
    }


    private void writeReferenceBytes(XadesSignedXml xadesSignedXml, Stream finalOctetStream, Reference reference, byte[] referencedBytes, System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform xmlTransform)
    {
        //Referansın transformalarını uygula.
        foreach (var transform in reference.TransformChain)
            referencedBytes = XMLHelper.ApplyTransform(referencedBytes, (System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform)transform);

        //Çıktı XML Node mu Octet Stream mi
        if (getReferenceOutputType(reference) == ReferenceOutputType.NODE_SET && isDOM(referencedBytes))
        {
            //var xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(referencedBytes);
            var xmlDoc = XMLHelper.LoadDocument(new MemoryStream(referencedBytes));
            referencedBytes = XMLHelper.ComputeCanonicalizedValueOfElement(xadesSignedXml, xmlDoc.DocumentElement, xmlTransform);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Referans ZD Diges Değeri : >> " + Convert.ToBase64String(DigestUtilities.CalculateDigest(DigestAlgorithms.SHA256.OID, referencedBytes)));

        finalOctetStream.Write(referencedBytes, 0, referencedBytes.Length);
    }

    private bool isDOM(byte[] bytes)
    {
        try
        {
            return startsWithXmlPreamble(bytes) && BuildDOM(bytes) != null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // NOT DOM
            return false;
        }
    }

    private XmlDocument BuildDOM(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes), "bytes is required");
        }

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            return BuildDOM(stream);
        }
    }

    private XmlDocument BuildDOM(Stream inputStream)
    {
        try
        {
            var document = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };

            var settings = GetSecureXmlReaderSettings();

            using var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream, settings);

            document.Load(reader);


            return document;
        }
        catch (XmlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to parse content (XML expected): {e.Message}", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"An error occurred while reading InputStream: {e.Message}", e);
        }
    }

    private XmlReaderSettings GetSecureXmlReaderSettings()
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit, // DTD'leri yasakla
            XmlResolver = null, // Dış varlıkların çözümlemesini devre dışı bırak
            IgnoreWhitespace = true,
            IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true,
            IgnoreComments = true
        };

        return settings;
    }

    private bool startsWithXmlPreamble(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        return StartsWith(byteArray, xmlPreamble) || StartsWith(byteArray, xmlWithBomPreamble);
    }

    private bool StartsWith(byte[] source, byte[] prefix)
    {
        if (source == null || prefix == null || source.Length < prefix.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Length; i++)
        {
            if (source[i] != prefix[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private ReferenceOutputType getReferenceOutputType(Reference reference)
    {
        var outputType = getDereferenceOutputType(reference.Uri);

        if (reference.TransformChain.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Transform transform in reference.TransformChain)
            {
                var algorithmUri = transform.Algorithm;
                outputType = getTransformOutputType(algorithmUri);
            }
        }

        return outputType;
    }

    private ReferenceOutputType getDereferenceOutputType(string referenceUri)
    {
        return IsSameDocumentReference(referenceUri) ? ReferenceOutputType.NODE_SET : ReferenceOutputType.OCTET_STREAM;
    }

    private ReferenceOutputType getTransformOutputType(string algorithmUri)
    {
        return transformsWithNodeSetOutput.Contains(algorithmUri) ? ReferenceOutputType.NODE_SET : ReferenceOutputType.OCTET_STREAM;
    }

    private bool IsSameDocumentReference(string referenceUri)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(referenceUri) || referenceUri.StartsWith("#");
    }

    public enum ReferenceOutputType
    {
        OCTET_STREAM,

        NODE_SET
    }

